# Google Voice On iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-voice

I downloaded Google Voice on my iPhone and the app downloaded without error, but anytime I open it there is already a Gmail address displaying. All I have to do is swipe over, and it enables the account.

How do I remove the default account that is showing that is NOT linked to anything on my iPhone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a google service which is not substantially different on Android. THis is a GOOGLE customer service question

Comment: @SteveChambers -> where would you recommend be the appropriate location to post the ?

Comment: Google Voice Support

Comment: @SteveChambers Is the question off-topic because it is a Google service, or because the program " is not substantially different on Android"?